# Zend Framework Zend_Date::WEEKDAY

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to get the weekday name from Zend_Date after setting the date with,

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->set(strtotime($newDate));
```

When I use  `return $date::WEEKDAY_NAME`, it always returns EE as the day name.

Comment: That syntax is bogus and you should see warnings or notices.  You may wish to review [the PHP manual section on constants](http://php.net/language.constants)

Answer (score 2):

The obvious red flag here is the double-colon: it's only used for static properties and class constants, so it can't be the way you'd get the actual "weekday name" string for this particular date object (or any instance data of any kind). Though PHP allows you to use the `$date` variable in this way, writing the correct `Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_NAME` makes it more clear you're accessing data from the *class*, not your *object*.

`Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_NAME` is just the constant for Zend_Date's weekday format string (that's the `EE` you're seeing). In fact, despite the name, it's actually the constant for the 2-char weekday abbreviation; `Zend_Date::WEEKDAY` is the complete name of the day.

You use these constants, as an argument to the methods on your `$date` object. `toString` is the method for returning formatted string representations of the date:

```
$date = new Zend_Date(strtotime($newDate));
return $date->toString(Zend_Date::WEEKDAY);
```

Comment: 'EE' is the ISO format to get the abbreviated weekday name, to get the real weekday name add the following code,

Zend_Date::setOptions(array('format_type' => 'php'));
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->set(strtotime($newDate));
return $date->toString('D');

For more formats read, http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/fr/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.phpformats

Comment: You specified `WEEKDAY_NAME` so that's what I used in my example (it is a very misleading name for the constant). `Zend_Date::WEEKDAY` will get you the full name without having to flip on the PHP format type setting.